# Delete folders from a directory once it's sbatch`ed in a for loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

I am running a command using `sbatch` for a tool on the server, that takes a lot of space. The command uses some directories (some files) from  a main directory(tq_first) in a for loop. I was wondering if there was a way to delete the directories once it's iterated in the loop and completely executed? will the remove command work there without interfering with the loop?

For e.g. for this loop

```
set -eu 


export PATH=/home/bin:${PATH}
reference_dir=/mnt/scratchb/REF


for fastq_dir in fastq_first/*; do
    barcode=`basename ${fastq_dir}`

    cmd="cellranger count \
        --id=${barcode} \
        --fastqs= ${fastq_dir}   \
        --sample=${barcode} \
        --transcriptome=${reference_dir} \
        --localcores=32 \
        --localmem=92"

    sbatch --nodes=1 \
        --cpus-per-task=32 \
        --mem=96G \
        --time=2880 \
        -o cellranger_count.%j.out \
        -e cellranger_count.%j.err \
        -J cellranger_count <<EOF

   cmd="rm -r $fastq_dir"
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start Cell Ranger count "`date`
echo ${cmd}
eval ${cmd}
echo "Done "`date`
cellranger count --version
EOF

done
```

Comment: Where are you running the command? There's no command being executed in your script. Also, the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) needs to be the first line of your file, you can't have it in the middle like that. Yes, you can absolutely delete the directory after running the command, but we need to see the actual script you use to be able to help you with it, one that shows us when you execute the command.

Comment: The script above rm works! I am just wondering if I can delete a folder after executing through cmd. and is it the right way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of giving more info in the comments.

Comment: No, that script won't work. You haven't closed the `for` loop and the `#!/bin/bash` is ignored as a comment. Please show us your _actual_ script, including the part where you execute `$sbatch` so we can understand what you are doing.

Comment: Are all people rude over here? @ArtemS.Tashkinov No, my question isn't about whether my script is right or not. I am simply asking if there is a way to delete folders once executing the cmd sbatch.

Comment: @terdon, there is a 'done' at the end of the file. I will add that. I just want to know if there's a way to delete files once I have used them to run a tool. If you don't have an input there please don't comment on my post. I do appreciate that you've tried, so thanks.

Comment: And I am trying to explain that yes, of course you can delete a folder if you don't need it anymore, but if you need us to help you and show you how to delete, we will need to see the actual script. Otherwise, all we can tell you is "sure, of course you can delete data you no longer need". But we don't know if "this is the right way to do this" since the way you show wouldn't work in the first place.

Comment: @terdon sure thanks. please see if the additional edit help it any better for you?

Comment: Almost. You have now shown part of the code (I am guessing you forgot to include the `cat <<EoF > somefile`, right?) that creates a script that will I guess be run to execute the command, is that right? Your code is still never actually executing `${cmd}` anywhere, you only have `eval ${cmd}` inside the EoF docstring. So does this mean you are generating another script and then running that? When, exactly, are you launching `$cmd`?

Comment: @terdon, hi thanks for the input, I have pasted my script as it is, hope it helps. My only concern with script is I want to make some space whilst its done using it while it iterates in the loop. thanks The script works just fine.

Comment: Is this really your script? That will just delete all of your fastq files without actually running anything. Are you sure? I _think_ what you want to do is write the final script, the part after the `#!/bin/bash` into a file and then execute that file, but you are not doing that and by the time you are writing `eval ${cmd}`, the `$cmd` variable only has `rm -r $fastq_dir`, so that's the only thing that will be executed.

Comment: @terdon okay that makes sense..

Comment: I am undeleting this since you have edited enough to make it answerable. It seems a shame to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is:

1. Submit one `cellranger` job to Slurm for each of your fastq directories.
2. Delete the directory.

However, that isn't what your script is doing. You have

```
    cmd="cellranger count \
    [. . . ]
```

And then you have:

```
    sbatch --nodes=1 \
         -J cellranger_count <<EOF
         [. . . ]
   cmd="rm -r $fastq_dir"
```

So in the job you are actually passing to `sbatch`, `$cmd` is just `rm -rf $fastq_dir` and not `cellrangercount...`.

In any case, I suspect that the `rm -rf "$fastq_dir"` won't work anyway, not unless the `sbatch` is running in the same directory, so you might want to use the full path in the `for` loop. For example, if your `fastq_first/` is actually `/home/echo94/data/fastq_first`, then you should change your `for` to be like this:

```
for fastq_dir in /home/echo94/data/fastq_first/*; do
```

Also, since you only want directories, you can add a slash to ensure that no files will be selected by the `for` loop:

```
for fastq_dir in /home/echo94/data/fastq_first/*/; do
```

You now have the full path to each directory so you can `rm $fastq_dir` from anywhere on the system. Putting all this together, this script is probably what you need:

```bsh
for fastq_dir in /home/echo94/data/fastq_first/*/; do
    barcode=`basename "$fastq_dir"`

    cmd="cellranger count \
        --id=${barcode} \
        --fastqs= ${fastq_dir}   \
        --sample=${barcode} \
        --transcriptome=${reference_dir} \
        --localcores=32 \
        --localmem=92"

    sbatch --nodes=1 \
        --cpus-per-task=32 \
        --mem=96G \
        --time=2880 \
        -o cellranger_count.%j.out \
        -e cellranger_count.%j.err \
        -J cellranger_count <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
set -ue
echo "Start Cell Ranger count `date`"
echo "$cmd" 
eval "$cmd"
echo "Done "`date` 
cellranger count --version
rm -r "$fastq_dir"
EOF

done
```

Comment: Thanks so much for editing this. I am going to try this and let you know if it works correctly!

Comment: You're welcome, @Echo94. I hope you understand why we were so pushy and insisted on more information now. As you can see, the devil's in the details! :)

Comment: thanks so much for but that didn't work with the rm command at the end of the file, may be because its out of the for loop.

Comment: @Echo94 please post a new question, give the script you actually used, make sure to chech what the value of the `$fastq_dir` variable is (did you use the full path as I suggested?) and explain exactly how it fails. Also try to save the script you are creating into a file instead of passing it with EOF so you can see what is actually being passed.